# How to access NFSv4 shared folder with Kerberos authentication without root rights

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, kerberos, ubuntu-18.04

I'm setting up a NFSv4 shared folder with Kerberos authentication. The issue I'm facing is that when the user on the client machine runs `mount /mnt` (see the fstab configuration below) he's not able to access /mnt directory.
It's due to the rights on the Kerberos ticket I guess. Indeed, when I'm doing so, I only get a ticket which belongs to root.

Client = 192.168.1.2 and server = 192.168.1.1 both are running Ubuntu 18.04.1

Here the command lines:

```
user@client:~$ mount -vvv /mnt
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Mon Sep 10 16:55:58 2018
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'proto=tcp,port=2049,sec=krb5p,vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.1,clientaddr=192.168.1.2'

user@client:~$ cd /mnt
bash: cd: /mnt: Permission denied

user@client:~$ ll /tmp/krb5ccmachine_DOMAIN.FR 
-rw------- 1 root root 1628 sept. 10 16:53 /tmp/krb5ccmachine_DOMAIN.FR

user@client:~$ sudo klist -c /tmp/krb5ccmachine_DOMAIN.FR 
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_DOMAIN.FR
Default principal: nfs/client.domain.fr@DOMAIN.FR

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
10/09/2018 16:53:42  11/09/2018 02:53:42  krbtgt/DOMAIN.FR@DOMAIN.FR
    renew until 11/09/2018 16:53:42
10/09/2018 16:53:42  11/09/2018 02:53:42  nfs/server.domain.fr@
    renew until 11/09/2018 16:53:42
10/09/2018 16:53:42  11/09/2018 02:53:42  nfs/server.domain.fr@DOMAIN.FR
    renew until 11/09/2018 16:53:42

root@client:~# klist -k /etc/krb5.keytab 
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 nfs/client.domain.fr@DOMAIN.FR
   3 nfs/client.domain.fr@DOMAIN.FR
```

I found that when I do a "kinit" of nfs/client.domain.fr with user rights and then runs the mount command, I can access to /mnt directory

```
user@client:~$ kinit nfs/client.domain.fr -t Documents/krb5.keytab 
keytab specified, forcing -k
user@client:~$ klist 
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: nfs/client.domain.fr@DOMAIN.FR

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
10/09/2018 17:22:59  11/09/2018 03:22:59  krbtgt/DOMAIN.FR@DOMAIN.FR
    renew until 11/09/2018 17:22:59

user@client:~$ mount /mnt
user@client:~$ cd /mnt
user@client:/mnt$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 sept.  4 10:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 sept.  4 11:09 ../
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 sept. 10 16:14 media/

user@client:/mnt$ ll /tmp/krb5cc*
-rw------- 1 user user 2037 sept. 10 17:23 /tmp/krb5cc_1000
-rw------- 1 root root 1628 sept. 10 17:23 /tmp/krb5ccmachine_DOMAIN.FR

user@client:/mnt$ sudo klist /tmp/krb5ccmachine_DOMAIN.FR 
[sudo] Mot de passe de user : 
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_DOMAIN.FR
Default principal: nfs/client.domain.fr@DOMAIN.FR

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
10/09/2018 17:23:35  11/09/2018 03:23:35  krbtgt/DOMAIN.FR@DOMAIN.FR
    renew until 11/09/2018 17:23:35
10/09/2018 17:23:35  11/09/2018 03:23:35  nfs/server.domain.fr@
    renew until 11/09/2018 17:23:35
10/09/2018 17:23:35  11/09/2018 03:23:35  nfs/server.domain.fr@DOMAIN.FR
    renew until 11/09/2018 17:23:35
```

My configurations files:

/etc/fstab on client machine

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=14d26733-1eb1-4c23-b6eb-7be5564675a6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
server:/    /mnt    nfs4    proto=tcp,port=2049,sec=krb5p,noauto,user   0   0
```

/etc/fstab on server:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=6edf6c8d-be74-4908-91c4-4c7bb453bc76 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/home/media /export/media   none    bind    0   0
```

/etc/exports on server:

```
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#       to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
/export         192.168.1.0/24(rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,sync,sec=krb5p,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/export/media   192.168.1.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,sync,sec=krb5p,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

User with uid=1000 and gid=1000 exists on client and server. I also tryed with root_squash option.

/etc/krb5.conf on both client and server:

```
[logging]
    default = FILE:/tmp/krb5libs.log
    kdc = FILE:/tmp/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/tmp/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
    default_realm = DOMAIN.FR

# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true

# The following encryption type specification will be used by MIT Kerberos
# if uncommented.  In general, the defaults in the MIT Kerberos code are
# correct and overriding these specifications only serves to disable new
# encryption types as they are added, creating interoperability problems.
#
# The only time when you might need to uncomment these lines and change
# the enctypes is if you have local software that will break on ticket
# caches containing ticket encryption types it doesn't know about (such as
# old versions of Sun Java).

#   default_tgs_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#   default_tkt_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#   permitted_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1

# The following libdefaults parameters are only for Heimdal Kerberos.
    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]
    DOMAIN.FR = {
        kdc = kdc.domain.fr
        admin_server = kerberos.domain.fr
        default_domain = domain.fr
    }

[domain_realm]
    .domain.fr = DOMAIN.FR
    domain.fr = DOMAIN.FR
```

/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server on server:

```
# Number of servers to start up
RPCNFSDCOUNT=8

# Runtime priority of server (see nice(1))
RPCNFSDPRIORITY=0

# Options for rpc.mountd.
# If you have a port-based firewall, you might want to set up
# a fixed port here using the --port option. For more information, 
# see rpc.mountd(8) or http://wiki.debian.org/SecuringNFS
# To disable NFSv4 on the server, specify '--no-nfs-version 4' here
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids --debug all"

# Do you want to start the svcgssd daemon? It is only required for Kerberos
# exports. Valid alternatives are "yes" and "no"; the default is "no".
NEED_SVCGSSD="yes"

# Options for rpc.svcgssd.
RPCSVCGSSDOPTS="-vvv"
```

/etc/default/nfs-common on both client and server:

```
# If you do not set values for the NEED_ options, they will be attempted
# autodetected; this should be sufficient for most people. Valid alternatives
# for the NEED_ options are "yes" and "no".


# Options for rpc.statd.
#   Should rpc.statd listen on a specific port? This is especially useful
#   when you have a port-based firewall. To use a fixed port, set this
#   this variable to a statd argument like: "--port 4000 --outgoing-port 4001".
#   For more information, see rpc.statd(8) or http://wiki.debian.org/SecuringNFS
STATDOPTS=

# Do you want to start the gssd daemon? It is required for Kerberos mounts.
NEED_GSSD=yes
```

/etc/hosts on both client and server:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

# server
192.168.1.1 server.domain.fr    server
192.168.1.1 domain.fr
# Client
192.168.1.2 client.domain.fr    client
```

logs of kdc:

```
sept. 10 16:48:06 server krb5kdc[545](info): setting up network...
krb5kdc: setsockopt(10,IPV6_V6ONLY,1) worked
krb5kdc: setsockopt(12,IPV6_V6ONLY,1) worked
krb5kdc: setsockopt(14,IPV6_V6ONLY,1) worked
sept. 10 16:48:06 server krb5kdc[545](info): set up 6 sockets
sept. 10 16:48:06 server krb5kdc[572](info): commencing operation
sept. 10 16:53:42 server krb5kdc[572](info): AS_REQ (8 etypes {18 17 20 19 16 23 25 26}) 192.168.1.2: NEEDED_PREAUTH: nfs/client.domain.fr@DOMAIN.FR for krbtgt/DOMAIN.FR@DOMAIN.FR, Additional pre-authentication required
sept. 10 16:53:42 server krb5kdc[572](info): AS_REQ (8 etypes {18 17 20 19 16 23 25 26}) 192.168.1.2: ISSUE: authtime 1536591222, etypes {rep=18 tkt=18 ses=18}, nfs/client.domain.fr@DOMAIN.FR for krbtgt/DOMAIN.FR@DOMAIN.FR
sept. 10 16:53:42 server krb5kdc[572](info): TGS_REQ (8 etypes {18 17 20 19 16 23 25 26}) 192.168.1.2: ISSUE: authtime 1536591222, etypes {rep=18 tkt=18 ses=18}, nfs/client.domain.fr@DOMAIN.FR for nfs/server.domain.fr@DOMAIN.FR
```

So now I'm only able to mount the shared folder and access it with root user on client machine because the ticket I get belongs to root. Is it possible to get a ticket which belongs to user ?
I would like to know if it possible to mount the shared directory with user and access it without doing the kinit before.

If you need more informations or have questions about my configuration don't hesitate.